# Can I clean hydronic polybutylene system with boiler cleaner?

Tags: plumbing

I have a hydronic snow melt system which uses polybutylene pipe (I know...) embedded in concrete. I am not going to tear up the driveway to replace it.

The glycol in the system is 20+ years old and needs replacement. I am also going to replace the boiler. How should I clean out the piping?

There many products which list safe piping but I want to be careful with PB

Comment: Boiler cleaner would be acidic I think. This sounds like it might degrade PB. How do you know the pipe needs cleaning? For that matter how do you know that the gylcol-water mixture needs changing? Does this system have metal pump parts that need anticorrosion additives?

Comment: How did you test the glycol fluid? I would drain some into a container and text with the car antifreeze testers - will tell you the level of protection.

Comment: I added info that I'm also replacing the boiler, so I can't just "top off" whatever the current glycol mixture is.

Comment: ... why not? Losing some doesn't change the mixture. Adding the same mix to fill the new pipes shouldn't change the mixture either.

Comment: Well I don't know what the mixture is from 20 years and multiple owners ago :)